# Address: Building number or House number?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

Which one is correct when we are talking about addresses:

> 1. Building number
> 2. House number

Comment: Include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic :)

Comment: Is it a building or is it a house? This includes no research, context, or clarification.

Comment: I've read a "House numbering" article on Wiki. "House number" term used far more often that a "Building number". However, in my recent conversation, my interlocutor didn't understand what do I mean by saying "Building number". He is not a native English speaker, neither do I, so I though that might be the issue... or not?

Comment: Building number can be used but can be confusing; one address could have more than one building.

Comment: Say "street number" and avoid the confusion.

Comment: Where?  In the US it would generally just be "street address".

Comment: In a large apartment complex the street number, building number, and apartment number are all separate things.

Comment: It's pretty unusual to treat the house number separately from the rest of the address. Addresses come in too many forms to ask for the number and street name separately, usually you just ask for the street address as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commonly, people use house numbers when talking about addresses. Building numbers apply when you're talking about larger non-separated apartments, or workplaces. For example, if I lived in an apartment, I might have my own house number if it was separated, but the apartments were connected with other apartments in a complex, and there are multiple complexes, I might say that I live in apartment 139 in building 3. *Usually*, you're safe just using house numbers unless you involve apartments or workplaces.